# Can't Delete aBarcode Image in VB.NET after it was printed (KeepAutomation)

Tags: vb.net

I am building a Label printer with Code 128 Barcode with KeepAutomation.

In the procedure i actually:

1. Encode the data to Barcode with the KeepAutomation Referenced module

   ```
   Private Sub MakeImage()
   Dim barcode As KeepAutomation.Barcode.Bean.BarCode = New KeepAutomation.Barcode.Bean.BarCode
   barcode.Symbology = KeepAutomation.Barcode.Symbology.Code128Auto
   barcode.CodeToEncode = Me.txtCatNum.Text
   barcode.X = 2
   barcode.Y = 100
   barcode.BottomMargin = 0
   barcode.LeftMargin = 0
   barcode.RightMargin = 0
   barcode.TopMargin = 0
   barcode.DisplayText = True
   barcode.ChecksumEnabled = True
   barcode.DisplayChecksum = True
   barcode.Orientation = KeepAutomation.Barcode.Orientation.Degree0
   barcode.BarcodeUnit = KeepAutomation.Barcode.BarcodeUnit.Pixel
   barcode.DPI = 72
   barcode.TextFont = New Font("Arial", 26.0F, FontStyle.Regular)
   barcode.ImageFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg
   barcode.generateBarcodeToImageFile(FileToUse)
   ```
2. Create a Jpeg image from the encoded data (with a static name to a specific location on the hard drive)
3. Place the image in a PrintDocument
4. Print It

But when I try to delete the file before I run the procedure again, It tells me it cannot delete the file because it is used by a application itself if published) or vshost32-clr2.exe (while debugging).

I have tried:

1. disposing the PrintDocument class
2. Disposing, Closing and ReOpening the form itself.

None of the above helped me.

Looking for a good idea (other then creating a different image for each label I create)

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: Is `barcode` disposable?

Comment: No , looked for it too, couldnt find any way to dispose it

Comment: What is FileToUse? Is it a string or a stream

Comment: FileToUse is a simple string containing a relative path to the applicatoin folder : ".\FileName.jpg"

Comment: This could be causing the lock. `barcode.generateBarcodeToImageFile(FileToUse)` What you can do is create a temporary file with random filename in a temporary folder, after creating the file, copy it to FileToUse. Then when your app opens, clear the tempoary folder. Because there's nothing you can do to change KeepAutomation API

Comment: it appears it was locked by the PrintDocument class , not the creation, so i solved it with FileStream...... see the answer..... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Friends,

I found the perfect answer for my problem with the lead from pinkfloydx33

I have created a FileStream for the jpeg i'm creating, Opened it as a "Read Only" and once finished placing it on the PrintDocument class, I can very easily overwrite/Delete it.

Here's The Code I use.....

```
       MakeImage()
    Dim fs As New FileStream(FileToUse, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromStream(fs), 20, 5, 150, 80)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Batch: ___________", BatchFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 97)
    fs.Dispose()
```

Conclusion, if I may.....

Whenever you open a file, especially when you do not need to modify it , Access it as FS and open as ReadOnly.....

Thanks again.